# Possible Reasons for Linux SSH hang

Tags: linux, ssh

We have Linux server run java application,this morning the server did not response for the ssh connection.when I ssh -v, it shows " **connection refused by remote host** ".We also have a vnc server run in that Linux and it does not work either.But the ftp server is ok in that server,we can upload file into the server.In the end,we did not found a way to remote connect to the system.

After we reboot the computer on site,the ssh server is working again.But We did not found a clue why ssh is not working? Have someone ever met ssh hang problem like this? Which file should we look into?How to prevent ssh hang? Thanks in advanced.

added:
I check the log from secure.log.it states many failed attemps like following and i check the ipaddress is not ours:

```
Feb 23 04:13:30 localhost sshd[1276]: Failed password for invalid user mantis from 112.78.127.235 port 57140 ssh2
```

It seems like the attacker is trying to login into my server all the time until our ssh service is not responding.

Comment: I would turn on more logging in /etc/ssh/sshd_config so if it happens again you might get more information.  Can I ask if you had physical access to the box or is it a VM or how did you manage to reboot it?  Could something automatically or someone disrupt your firewall settings?

Comment: simply ask someone to reboot it by hand.：）

Comment: IMO, this Question is off-topic.  It is nothing to do with programming.  It should be either on http://serverfault.com or http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH probably didn't "hang".  The "Connection refused" response implies that no application was listening for incoming connections on the SSH port.  It is most likely that the SSH service had died.

Check the log files.  There is a good chance that there are clues in the logs (somewhere) to help explain what had happened.

If the logs don't give a definite explanation, I'd be considering the possibility that your server had been hacked ...

Comment: Our server indeed has internet public address,I am also worried about be hacked.Our server need internet access,how can we know if being hacked? thanks

Comment: @snow8261 - There is no general answer to that.  You would need to consult a forensic security consultant.  Alternatively, you could *assume* that it has been hacked, and rebuild it on a fresh OS install as a precaution.  (And pay proper attention to hardening it against future attacks.)

Comment: It seems there were lots of attempts in short period time in the log.I think maybe that is the reason why ssh service is not responding.But i  am just wondering why ssh service is so fragile.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a firewall issue, either on the box itself or somewhere else in the network. You can verify that ssh is running and listening with `netstat -ta | grep :22`. If it is not, it indeed is a problem with SSH itself.

Comment: I doubt this ... unless someone has deliberately configured the firewall to send misleading responses to TCP/IP connection requests.  (And that is unlikely to give a failure that was cured by a simple reboot.)

Comment: I thought it is a firewall issue,but after reboot,the ssh is working again,it sounds not like a firewall issue.